# How to select columns without put a non-aggragate column in group by clause

Tags: python, sql, django, model, group-by

I want to know how to select columns without put them in group by clause
E.G:

```
select id, name, count(score) from users
group by name
order by count(score) desc
```

Here I don't want to group by the ID column

Someone?

TIP: Django doesn't allow me to use min, max, avg, top, I need forced to select the ID without functions.

Comment: Which RDBMS? It seems that MySQL supports selecting columns not in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can you provide us sample data and expected result?

Comment: drop the id column from the select statement.... it is meaningless here.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.

This means that the only way to achieve what you want in a single query, is to use an `OUTER JOIN` statement. The Django ORM does not support `OUTER JOIN` statements from a table to itself, as far as I know.

The only way to get what you want (a list of all models, including ID, with the count of the number of occurances for each unique name), apart from using a raw SQL statement, is to use 2 separate queries and process them in Python.

I do wonder, though, if you didn't mean to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. `COUNT` adds 1 for each `NON-NULL` value, including `0`, while `SUM` adds the actual numeric values in the column.

Anyway, an example would look like this:

```
qs = Foo.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('id')) # or sum=Sum('score')
count = dict((x['name'], x['count']) for x in qs)
object_list = Foo.objects.all()
for foo in object_list:
    foo.count = count['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Any column that does not have a calculation performed on it needs to be included in the GROUP BY.
Why do you want it in the SELECT but not in the GROUP BY?

Comment: Because i have a count that will be usless if i start to group by ID

Comment: In that case - why include the ID column in the results?

Comment: Because django force me to include the ID as a primary key to search for models.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use aggregate function for example `min` to select one one id for a group.

```
select min(id) as id, name, count(score) as cnt 
from users
group by name
order by count(score) desc
```

You can also use `max` function instead.

2nd solution:

```
select u.id, u.name, 
(select count(u1.score) from users u1 where u1.name = u.name ) as cnt
from users u
```

Comment: I can't use min and max and anything, django dosent allow me to use this.

Comment: Do you need id column?

Comment: Yes, because django force me to use this column to search for models.

Comment: OK, so if you have 3 rows with name `John`, we will group by to one row, which id you want to display? Can you try may 2nd solution?